# Is there a way to change a final static constant, statically used in different classes, without instantiating its class?

Tags: java, parameters, static, constants

I'm working on a game and have a class named Constants that preserves all the variables that aren't unique to a class/instance of a class. One of these constants is the number of players that are playing. When beginning this project this value has been assigned to 2, but now I would like to extend the game and give user a possibility to chose between (lets say 2,3,4) players that will be playing. Since this is an important number that appears in multiple classes, I'm searching for a way to change its value without having to instantiate anything, just assign the value (2,3 or 4) when the program is executed and has been passed one of these values as a parameter.

Perhaps I'm not approaching the problem correctly and there's an easier way, if you have any suggestions, I'd be very thankful for any help.

Comment: If the number of players is not constant, don't define it as constant.

Comment: A static field or method never requires you to create any instance of the class to work with it. That's kind of the point of static members

Comment: Well, you could change the field from being a constant (static and final) to just a static value (i.e. remove the final keyword) but that might not solve your problem entirely (e.g. if some code just copies it before it gets changed) and generally using statics isn't the best design (there are reasons to use static fields but you should definitely know what you're doing and when to use it). It might be better to have something like a `Game` or `Match` instance that contains the number of players and which is passed arround. I'd put in the effort to redesign earlier than later.

Comment: @Thomas So the best solution here would be passing this information when calling different methods? No way of giving the whole game access to this information from the beginning ?

Comment: Well, it depends on your design but the classes interested in this data might need access to the currently running game/match anyway so why not pass that instance around? You could also try to make it available as a singleton but those are harder to get and use right. There are other more spophisticated options as well (e.g. dependency injection) but those might be too complex for you atm.